# console repeatedly executes anonymous code

Tags: developer-console

Some how, when I last used the developer console....I re-ran a previously entered piece of anonymous Apex code. Now, I find that the console is repeatedly executing that piece of code and I cannot find a way of stopping.

I have deleted the class that the code was calling; I have removed the code from the anonymous window; have exited the console and shutdown my browser. Still, is continuously executing it.

Anybody know how to stop this?

Comment: What exactly was the code?

Comment: Is the code scheduled?  How can it execute a method from a class that doesn't exist??  This is extremely bizarre, and I recommend issuing a ticket with Salesforce Support asap

Comment: check out Setup -> Monitor -> Jobs and see if there's a job calling your code in there

Comment: Are you seeing any Debug Log Entries getting created? If so, for which user?